# ALSA : snd_pcm_readn need constant read delay

Tags: c, linux, audio, alsa

How to achieve constant read delay from snd_pcm_readn() ? I tried (144 frames read, for 4 channel mic, 8000Hz).

What I expect is 18 millisecond read delay for each call to snd_pcm_readn() :

```
 18ms, 18ms, 18ms , 18ms, 18ms, 18ms, 18ms , 18ms, 18ms, 18ms, 18ms , 18ms ....
```

. But what I observed the following pattern in the oscilloscope  :

```
 2ms, 2ms, 2ms ,2ms , 64ms, 2ms, 2ms, 2ms 2ms ,, 64ms, 2ms, 2ms, 2ms, 2ms, 64ms ....
```

It seems to have some buffering happens in snd_pcm_readn(), if data is buffered the api returns faster. Although this observation averages to 18ms, I need a blocking behavior of constant 18ms for each call to  snd_pcm_readn().

(average time of read is 18ms anyway - I don't want average behavior - it should be exact 18ms for every read)

How to achieve this using ALSA?

Comment: You better try posting this question on alsa mailing list

Comment: What period size have you set for the PCM device?

Comment: @CL , period size is 576 (144*4)

Comment: You know that the period size is measured in frames, not in samples? It should be 144.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. By the way I fixed the issue by adding  snd_pcm_wait ()